# Give an example of an ideal that is not a subring, and a subring that is not an ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give an example of an ideal that is not a subring, and a subring that is not an ideal. For the latter part, let $\mathbb{Q}$ be a ring and consider $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then we observe that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$ since the multiplication of integer and rational number gives rational number. But for the first part, I have no idea. Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each ideal of a ring is a subring of that ring (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29#Subring)), therefore no such example can be found.

Comment: I thought an ideal is a subset of a ring but not subring ?

Comment: @Idonknow: Can you give the definition of a subring please. Maybe my answer is wrong. It depends on what definition you use.

Comment: This depends on if you want your rings to have an identity or not.

Comment: the definition of subring: An nonempty subset of ring which closed under subtraction and multiplication

Comment: @Idonknow: And the definition of an ideal?

Comment: Ideal: A subset of a ring which closed under addition and for all $r \in R$(ring) , $rI \subset I$ and $Ir \subset I$

Comment: If $a,b\in I$ then $(-1)b=-b\in I\Longrightarrow a+(-b)=a-b\in I$. Therefore $I$ is closed under subtraction. That being said, is my answer correct?

Answer (score 2):

The set of even integers is an example of a subring which is not an ideal.

Comment: why is not an ideal