# normal subgroups VS Ideal(commutative)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let the $G$ is a abelian group and $R$ is a commutative Ring

Say subgroup $H (\le G)$ and subring  $S(\le R)$

It is trivial that H is the normal subgroup of the G

But Does S the ideal of the R? (I couldn't find any examples.)

If not, what condition we need that S is a ideal of the R?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098217/subring-which-is-not-an-ideal) are more examples of subrings which are not ideals.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/339386/29335) is another post that completely answers the question. it came up right at the top when I searched "example of a subring that is not an ideal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ but not an ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take diagonals. You always have the subring $\Delta_R = \lbrace (r,r) \mid r \in R \rbrace \subset R^2$, which is never an ideal except for $R = 0$ as you can multiply $(1,1)$ by $(1,0)$ then (for me a ring is a commutative unitary ring btw.).